# questions regarding table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using article for my lecture note.. but in the content i am having the problem that the title of the chapter is not formatted in correct manner.`

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{lgrind,latexcad}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,thesisb1,fancyhdr,mathrsfs, 
indentfirst,dsfont,lipsum,multicol}

\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                           {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
 \pagestyle{fancy}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
 \numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
 \numberwithin{table}{chapter}
 \newcommand{\ntt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\input{unit3.tex}

\end{document}
```

In this i am having my table of contents as,

[image]

Note that the third chapter is not in the correct manner.. i should have in this way

```
3 The complex potential for two dimensional, irrorational,   
  incompressible flow
```

Help me to do the correction...
In addition i am giving the chapter 3 codes als...

```
\chapter{The complex potential for two dimensional, irrorational, incompressible flow}
  \section{Complex potential}
  Suppose that  $z=x+iy$ and that $W=f(z)$,
  \begin{equation}
   W=f(z)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)\\
  \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)=f(x+iy)\\
\end{equation}
```

Comment: While it's good that you add an example code, it would be better if you made the example *minimal* and *compilable* as well. For example, I would think that you can reduce the document part of your code to `\tableofcontents\chapter{Whatever that long chapter title was}`, and much of the preamble can likely be removed as well.

Comment: ya.. i will....@TorbjørnT.

Comment: You should also add a more descriptive title than "questions regarding table of contents".

Comment: Especially try to avoid `thesisb1` in your example. If your error disappears by removing this package, we need the code of this package to check what is happening. Why aren't you using the `report` class, if you want to use chapters? Would be much easier to switch the documentclass than defining everything as theorems.

Comment: actually report giving its title in very large font.. so that i am using article @LaRiFaRi

Comment: OK, but I guess it is quite simple to redefine the size of the titles. But well, not the topic here. Still my question: Do you need `thesisb1` in order to show us your problem?

Comment: yes.. if i delete this.. it is showing error.@LaRiFaRi

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you only posted the minimal amount of code necessary to see your problem. As it is I can't reproduce your issue with what have posted because:

- with `\documentclass{article}`  the `\chapter` command is not defined. I use `\documentclass{report}` below.
- with `\textwidth 6in` I find that the contents line for your chapter 3 in your table of contents fits on one line. Using `\textwidth 5in` I get the issue you ask about.
- I didn't use your fonts, however, so perhaps this is the difference.

The easiest way to fix this is to put a `\newline` into your chapter heading. With the page width that I think you are using this does not affect the chapter heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\textwidth 5in
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The complex potential for two dimensional, irrational,\newline incompressible flow}
  \section{Complex potential}
\newpage
another chapter
\end{document}
```

This seems fix your problem in the table of contents but I think that you also have a problem with overlapping chapter and section headings in the running page headers -- perhaps your use of `fancyhdr` fixes this but for my mock-up of your code it didn't.

All of the chapter/section commands have an optional argument for shortening the running titles. Using this you should be able to fix these issues if they do exist:

```
\chapter[A shorter running title]{The complex potential for two dimensional, irrational,\newline incompressible flow}
```